# the opposite of "nindastuti"

Tags: scripture, reference-request

From [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Hinduism-What-is-Ninda-Stuti), in response to a question about what Ninda Stuti is:

> Ninda Stuti is basically a hymn of god in which he is teased.
>
> It comes out of a feeling of closeness to god. Such devotees feel that god is their own and so tease him.
>
> For example, there was a poet called Sri-Natha and once while he was traveling, he could not find water to quench his thirst. He came upon a Shiva linga(he was a Shiva devotee) and he prayed to him.
>
> The poem goes like this…
>
> > “It may be acceptable if a wealthy man marries even 16000 women(referring to Krishna)
> > But does a beggar need two wives? (referring to Shiva who is an ascetic)
> > Let go of Ganga! Parvati is enough for you.”
>
> Water started pouring from the Shiva linga.

Is the opposite behavior present in any story or scripture? That is, denigrating someone under the pretext of praising them?

Comment: Afaik, the context of the question, pertains to kavya shastra. Alankaras are poetic devices(embellishments) like metaphor, similies, etc .So supposedly nindha stuti might fall under shlesha alankara. It could be the right assumed by the poet owing to poetic licence